# Putty / Bash alt + left/right arrow key to move cursor by word

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, putty

I can't get this putty to handle alt + left/right properly.

(Edit: By "properly", I obviously mean the way I have grown used to moving the cursor about;-)

Usually I can do:

```
cat > /dev/null
..&lt;hold alt and left arrow&gt;..
```

to get the proper key. In this case I get: ^[^[[D

I then proceed to do:

```
bind '^[^[[D:backward-word'
```

I've also tried:

```
bind '\e\e[D:backward-word'
```

Please note that this problem is the same in screen (with TERM=screen) and outside of screen (with TERM=xterm).

Any tips on what I should try next? Any putty options that need to be enabled/disabled?

Comment: Take a look at `stty -a` and see if any of the settings match what you want to do

Comment: To make your `bind` command work, you just need to add a set of double quotes: `bind '"\e\e[D":backward-word'`

Comment: This question put me on the right track to fix a similar issue with zsh (solution: use `cat > /dev/null` to identify the key code, then use `bindkey`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This format of `bind` doesn't work for me either for some reason, but I've had success with `bind -f`.

~/.bashrc:

```
if [ -f ~/.readline-bindings ] ; then
    bind -f ~/.readline-bindings
fi
```

~/.readline-bindings:

```
"\e[1;3D": backward-word
"\e[1;3C": forward-word
```

Note the space after the `:` character. Obviously you should use your own control sequence here.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to make it work by inspiration of your post.

Comment: You can add the contents of `~/.readline-bindings` to `~/.inputrc` and drop the `bind -f`.

Comment: The problem is that vi usually gives a keycode when i do ctrl+v followed by alt+left arrow. This time it only gave away "^[", to make it into "^[^[[D" it's not enough to just copy paste, it needs to be the actual single character escape key "^[" instead of two separate chars. No idea why vi suddenly behaves like this, but that may be for another time:-) Thanks

Comment: As a note to those who want to use Emacs to get this behaviour: editing `~/.inputrc` you can press Ctrl-q to quote the next character you type. For me I had to type `"\e`, then Ctrl-q Esc (adds `^[`), then type `[D": backward-word"`, and add a similar line mapping `\e^[[C` to `forward-word`.

Answer (score 0):

Preserving and improving on helpful comments by [@Geo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/510842/geo) and [@AlexC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28234/alexc), the following works for me in `4.4.12(1)-release` bash.

```
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
```

works for me, in `.inputrc`.

New binds can be tested in a new `bash` shell, with `$ bind -f .inputrc.draft`.

The format with `\e` works better in editing, copying, and viewing in terminal, than including the escape sequence directly, `^[` character. `man bash` covers `\e` as an escape sequence that builtins interpret.

---

I did not having success with entries as described,

```
"\e[1;3D": backward-word
"\e[1;3C": forward-word
```

in `4.4.12(1)-release` bash.

Preserving key helpful comments into an answer

> The problem is that vi usually gives a keycode when i do ctrl+v followed by alt+left arrow. This time it only gave away "^[", to make it into "^[^[[D" it's not enough to just copy paste, it needs to be the actual single character escape key "^[" instead of two separate chars -@Geo

> As a note to those who want to use Emacs to get this behaviour: editing ~/.inputrc you can press Ctrl-q to quote the next character you type. For me I had to type "\e, then Ctrl-q Esc (adds ^[), then type [D": backward-word", and add a similar line mapping \e^[[C to forward-word -@AlexC